# Mongoose create new objectId while updating document inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, keystonejs

Following is schema :-

```
  Domain.add({
  domainName: {type: Types.Text, required: true, initial: true, index: true},
  labconfigs :{type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'LabConfig',required: false,many: true},
  });

Domain.schema.add({
  userlevels: {
    type: [{
      labId : String,
      userlevel: String
    }]
  }
});
```

This is my sample database, Robomongo output

```
Domain 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f82400198c"),
    "domainName" : "ABC.com",
    "userlevels" : [ 
        {
            "labId" : "104",
            "userlevel" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "401",
            "userlevel" : "false"
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "202",
            "userlevel" : "true"
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "102",
            "userlevel" : "true"
        }
    ],
    "labconfigs" : [ 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001986"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001987"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001988"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001989")
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

So what i do is simply update my document for userlevels field ( Userlevels field is array of JSON objects).

To update my userlevels field , so i gave this following Mongoose function with $set

```
Domain.model.update( {_id: req.params.id},  {$set: {"userlevels": userauthlevel.labpublishedIDs}}, function(err, result) {
                       if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
```

Value of labPublishedIDs is :-

```
{ labpublishedIDs: 
   [ { labId: '102', userlevel: 'false' },
     { labId: '104', userlevel: 'true' },
     { labId: '202', userlevel: 'false' },
     { labId: '401', userlevel: 'true' } ] }
```

But now after my update function it creates a new ObjectId with each Array Object. 
I couldn't understand reasons. Maybe Values coming in update are changed & it creates new ObjectId. Any reasons why ???

Here is sample output after update function

```
/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f82400198d"),
    "domainName" : "ABC.com",
    "userlevels" : [ 
        {
            "labId" : "102",
            "userlevel" : "false",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5900de7ddcbe0a29fd7aaccb")
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "104",
            "userlevel" : "true",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5900de7ddcbe0a29fd7aacca")
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "202",
            "userlevel" : "false",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5900de7ddcbe0a29fd7aacc9")
        }, 
        {
            "labId" : "401",
            "userlevel" : "true",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5900de7ddcbe0a29fd7aacc8")
        }
    ],
    "labconfigs" : [ 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001986"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001987"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001988"), 
        ObjectId("5900dbdb4bc4c2f824001989")
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it gives me pain but finally  i was able to solve on my own.
 I just have to update my domain schema to not create objectId in subdocuments. This can be done by adding _id:false in your schema.

```
Domain.schema.add({
  userlevels: {
    type: [{
      _id : false,
      labId : String,
      userlevel: String
    }]
  }
});
```

But still cannot figure out why it adds objectId in subdocument 
Any reasons why would mongoose does this.